# Node Js, Git, Heroku: Git commits not pushing to git because large file was committed several commits in the past

Tags: node.js, git, express, heroku

***See edit below***

I'm trying to push to git, and then to heroku. However, I think that my push to git is being interupted because of the 'node_modules' folder.

The error I get:
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected...
To git@github...git
  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github...git'

The large file is libsass.lib, which is within node_modules.

So I've added node_modules to my .gitignore file just like this:

```
node_modules/
```

And I've ran this command to remove node modules from the git push:

```
git rm --cached node_modules
git add .
git commit -am "Remove ignored files"
```

It says it works, but then I try and push again and get the same error.

What's my next step? Thanks a lot.

**Edit. The duplicate question attached above did not help my problem. Here is what I did that eventually worked as I would expect.**

I had 9 commits on my system that would not push, presumably because my first push failed. This will erase things, so backup your files. So I worked backward, removing them using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1 // Destroys the current commit, moving backward by one setp.
```

Once I made it to the start, I created my gitignore file for node_modules. Then I removed it's reference from git:

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
git commit -m "remove node_modules"
git push origin master
```

My heroku instance was ahead in terms of commit, so I then forced a push to reset.

```
git push -f heroku
```

Now everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing everything from git then adding everything back again:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "re-add all for fix"
```

**Be careful!** Remember to commit all your changes before doing this ;)

Comment: This did not work, but thank you for the idea.

Comment: How would this help?